# tell Intellij that class is part of library, so it's normal that methods are unused

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is giving me warnings when my methods are unused. Except that I am developing a library, so the methods are used in other projects but never in the current library.

I know I can tell IntelliJ to remove warning if I associate the methods with a specific annotation (That's what I do for reflective methods).

But is there a way to avoid adding annotation to stop the warnings?

Or at least to provide annotation only for the class, not for each method within the class?

Comment: Write a unit test for your library methods, then they will be used.

Comment: I guess that's the best answer. I self-taught myself and never learned how to do unit tests, so that would be a steep learning curve... my bad.

Comment: Can sometimes be quite simple: `assertEquals(4, Lib.square(2))` (`square` being your library method)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to use @SuppressWarnings("ALL") annotation at the class level for suppressing the warnings.

```
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public interface UserService {
     void f1();

     void f2();

}
```

Second method is also fairly simple which will allow you to suppress warnings for whole IDE. Go and disable inspection for unused methods globally - in Preferences go to Editor > Inspections > Java > Declaration redundancy > Unused declaration and untick Methods.

Comment: what would be the value for suppressing only warning for "unused methods"?

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unused")

Comment: Well, how do I keep the warning for unused fields?

Comment: I think, if your question is answered kindly provide an up vote the response.

Comment: I think the question is not answered. I don't want to suppress warnings for every unused thing, just for the methods.